# Zsh: Automatically modify executed command

Tags: terminal, zsh, osx

I've recently installed grc (generic colorizer) to my system via MacPorts, giving me the ability to get colorized output for plenty of commands which by default don't support it (see screenshot below).
[image: Example of grc with traceroute.]
I would like to make using grc automatic, however not for specific commands, but for every command. I use zsh as my shell.

Essentially whenever I execute `command -parameter 1 2 3` I would like it to automatically be executed as `grc command -parameter 1 2 3`.
I'm not looking to use aliases, for example `traceroute` alias to `grc traceroute`, as I'm adding more and more commands for grc to colorize.

I've looked into preexec and precmd configurations for .zshrc, but I haven't found a way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it by redefining the accept-line widget:

```
add-grc() { [[ $BUFFER = grc* ]] || BUFFER="grc $BUFFER"; zle .$WIDGET "$@"; }
zle -N accept-line add-grc
```

However, it could cause problem for commands like "for i (..)", "var=x", "f() {"...

Comment: Good point. I couldn't think of any problems this solution could create myself, but you're right on this behalf. Thank you for your time.

Comment: One drawback with this method is that history will show `grc` at the start of every command.

Answer (score 6):

Other alternative. Same kind of potential problems:

```
TRAPDEBUG() { eval "grc $ZSH_DEBUG_CMD"; setopt errexit; }
```

I would use an "alias" for every command that needs "grc" instead of trying to figure out exceptions for the solutions posted here.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `grc.zsh` that's part of `grc` which can be found [here](https://github.com/garabik/grc/blob/master/grc.zsh). It has aliases for all supported commands.
See this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33363572/463)